# Resolution is suddenly really, really high and I can't seem to change it

Tags: macbook, resolution, release-hera

I came back into Elementary OS on my Macbook Pro and suddenly the resolution was really, really high. I tried to go in and change it but it only offers a single option. Everything is super small and text is so small that it's illegible. Any suggestions on how I can correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an option itno System settings > Displays in the bottom left part of the window called "Scalling factor"? You can try Pixel Doubled from there to see if it helps.

Comment: It did kind of help but it also made many apps display improperly and seemed to mess up the alignment in other places.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide screenshots of both scalling factor enabled and disabled? You can insert pictures in your post just by drag and drop it into the editor, also you can use "Conseal text" option of the screenshot application if you have some sensual infomation on the windows.